# Resolving a promise in a redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a reactjs project that uses redux. I am making the following fetch request:

```
function fetchQuote() {
  return fetch("http://localhost:8080/quote").then(function (response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    // Read the response as json.
    return response;
  })
    .then(function (response2) {
      // Do stuff with the JSON
      return response2.text();
    })
    .then(function (response3) {
      return response3
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
    })
}
```

I want to use this function to return the value of a string in the backend of my project. I access this function through my action creator, like so:

```
export const getQuote = () => ({ type: 'GET_QUOTE', payload: fetchQuote() });
```

This then goes to a reducer:

```
const quoteReducer = (state = { title: 'test', id: 1 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_QUOTE:
      console.log(action);
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

However, when I `console.log(action)` I get the following:

```
{type: "GET_QUOTE", payload: Promise}
payload
:
Promise
__proto__
:
Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]
:
"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]
:
"tes11t"
type
:
"GET_QUOTE"
```

I want the promise to be resolved so that I can directly access the value being returned by the fetch request. But I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: i think this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response here would help you some way just try this

Answer (score 1):

That's because `getQuote` passes a Promise to the reducer, not a returned value. But you know that.

This is a scenario when you have to make some operation asynchronously and dispatch actions that return value of that asynchronous operations **when** they complete. You can't do that in Object that you pass but you can utilize redux middleware. There are libraries designed to solve that like [`redux-thunk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk), [`redux-saga`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-saga), [`redux-observable`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-observable) and more.